# Google deadline for Symantec will it affect the live App

Tags: android, google-chrome, symantec

Regarding the Symantec® certificates issued before December 2017 are being phased out of support as per the following URL (https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7662561?hl=en)

As mentioned, this clearly applies to managed Chrome Browsers and Chrome devices, but my worry is what will happen to native android apps? Are they affected? If yes then what would be the impact of it? As most of the android apps make use HttpsURLConnection to call HTTPS API.

Regards,
Murtaza